# Drupal 7 displaying fields of a custom node type

Tags: php, drupal-7, field, content-type

I have a page.tpl.php where I want to display images inside a div.
So I created a custom content type called "Slider" , then I created a field called "image" where the machine_name for it is "field_image_slider".

Then I started adding contents (content->add content->Slider ..)

The problem is that I don't know how to display the images of this custom content!
what is the PHP code that I should place inside page.tpl.php in order to display the fields of this custom content?

This is node.tpl.php :

```
    <?php 

        print render($content['field_image_slider']);

    ?>
```

And this is page.tpl.php :

```
    <div id="banner_slides" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

       <?php 
          if (!empty($node)) :
            $fieldImage = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_slider');
                if ($fieldImage):
                   print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($node->field_image_slider['und'][0]['uri']). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
                endif; 
           endif; 
        ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: You need to review Drupal theme, it seems you mix between tpl files, page.tpl is something and node.tpl is something else, check [Overview of theme files](https://www.drupal.org/node/171194)

Answer (score 0):

The fields of a node are shown in node.tpl.php 
If you want a field to show in that template, you need to enable it in the field display of the contenttype (admin -> structure -> content types -> [type name] -> manage display.

Here you can change the visibility of the label or change the display of the field itself.

Comment: I Edit my comment, check the added codes
I want the fields of custom content (slider) to be viewed in page.tpl.php

Comment: The output usually is printed in the system_main block; if that block is active in a region the output will be printed in the page.tpl
You can't print the contents of a node in the page.tpl.php (well, you can but really, really shouldn't).

Comment: Check the last Edit , I printed the image of the field and it works fine , but it works only for one field. 
I want it to miltiple images , you have any idea for that ?
@Web-Beest

Comment: No no no no no.. You really shouldn't do this! Never, ever, access a node or its fields in the template. Use a preprocess function for this (hook_preprocess_node or hook_preprocess_page). 
If you want multiple values, check the field settings if it allows more than one value. Use the correct field formatter to display an image, so you can choose an imagecache preset.

Comment: why no ?
Can you please edit or post an answer where I can use preprocess function for this ? 
But please take in consideration that I want to display ALL FIELDS of a custom content type.
Example : post all fields of type "field_image_slider" of a content of type "slider" . 
I've spent 2 days searching for a solution man ! @Web-Beest

Comment: "No" because it goes against all that is Drupal; it's like trying to nailing a picture to the wall with a bulldozer. Just because you can, does not mean that you should. 

I think you just want to show these fields, so create a View block-display (admin -> structure -> views), selecting the field of your content type and outputting the field using the image formatter. The block can than be set to the correct region (admin -> structure -> blocks).

Comment: Im using drupal 7 , there is no view in the structure ; 
But anyway , I know Im getting you annoyed and I'm sry , but the main idea is that I have an image slider in my page , and I want that when I insert a content of type "Slider" , to be added to this image slider !
That's it .. whatever the solution you have I would extremely appreciate it . @Web-Beest

Comment: You need to enable the Views / Views UI module to do what I mentioned earlier. Views is a type of query builder with which you can select fields and present them a certain way. With views_slideshow (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) you can present the fields as a slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
      if (!empty($node)) :
        $fieldImage = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_slider');
            if ($fieldImage):
               print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($node->field_image_slider['und'][0]['uri']). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
            endif; 
       endif; 
    ?>

</div>
```